# "Smile because it confuses people..." - when is this said by the Joker?

Tags: dialogue, the-dark-knight

There is a line that is all over internet attributed as being said by the Joker:

> Smile because it confuses people. Smile because it's easier than explaining what's killing you inside.

[image: Joker]

But I can't remember from Batman: The Dark Knight when Joker character might have said this... All posters from internet contain Heath Ledger's Joker with the quote.

Is it said by him at all? If so then in which scene? Or is it from a past Batman movie? Or from the comics? Can anybody recall anything?

Comment: He definitely doesn't say this in *The Dark Knight*, unless it is in a deleted scene that I haven't seen, but that's all I know.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions and I guess this is not allowed in a single post. You should simply ask - 'is this a quote rightly attributed to the Joker', and if it is, then the answer will definitely tell where it is from.

Comment: @Ankit yeah bro, why so serious ?? Lets put a smile on that face ... haha

Comment: @AtanuCSE :-) Right, but I don't think this quote is from Joker either in movies or comics.

Comment: Yap I also think that. That's why asked the question.Obsessed with Joker, but this isn't kind of thing that he would've said. So curious if this line ever said in any version of the Joker from comics to past movies. @Ankit

Comment: I think this is the best answer you can have: https://www.reddit.com/r/batman/comments/3foxbt/joker_quote/

Comment: If you go back to the movie that Jack Nicholson plays the Joker there is a quote that is close to this one. He says "I'm only laughing on the outside my smile is just skin deep if you could see inside i'm really crying you might join me for a weep."

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**I really doubt that The Joker has ever said this.**

You are right when you say that the quote is all over the Internet, and quite often attributed to Heath Ledger's version of The Joker. But Heath Ledger only played The Joker once, in *The Dark Knight*, and he definitely didn't say it in that film.

What's more, not a single instance of those quote that I can find (and there are [a lot of instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=smile+because+it+confuses+people+because+its+easier+than+explaining+whats+killing+you+isnide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&safe=active#safe=active&q=smile+because+it+confuses+people+because+it%27s+easier+than+explaining+what%27s+killing+you+inside)) actually offers a source for the quote other than "The Joker".

Add in the fact that this doesn't even sound like something The Joker would say, and is instead something an angst-ridden Tumblr teenager might think is deep, and I think it is safe to say that this is a classic example of someone making up a quote and attaching it to someone iconic in order to give it more credibility.

**In short - I doubt the character of The Joker has *ever* said this.**

Comment: Wikiquote has a collection of quotes by the Joker spanning, movies, comic books & video games. Above mentioned quote appears nowhere. https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Joker

Comment: I also think that. May be you're right. Some teenage kid want this to be famous so added up with Joker.

Comment: As my digital poster of Abraham Lincoln says, "Don't believe everything you read on the Internet just because there's a picture with a quote next to it."